# Monitoring NSEvents using addGlobalMonitorForEvents missing gesture events

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have really strange problem:

My background service is trying to detect, if user is idle by monitoring `NSEvents` using `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: mask, handler: handler)`. So far so good, I'm able to get mouse and keyboard notifications like mouseMoved, leftMouseDown or keyDown without problems.

But I noticed, that I don't receive events for gestures like 3 fingers swipe to show mission control.
At the moment I put all `NSEventMask` values into `matching:`, because I want to monitor any user activity. There is `NSEventMask.any` value, but if I use it, I somehow don't get any events at all...

here is my code:

EventMonitor-Wrapper

```
public class EventMonitor {
    private var monitor: Any?
    private let mask: NSEventMask
    private let handler: (NSEvent?) -> ()

    public init(mask: NSEventMask, handler: @escaping (NSEvent?) -> ()) {
        self.mask = mask
        self.handler = handler
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    public func start() {
        self.monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: mask, handler: handler)
    }

    public func stop() {
        if self.monitor != nil {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(self.monitor!)
            self.monitor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Tracking-Service:

```
private static let inactivityEvents: NSEventMask = [NSEventMask.leftMouseDown, NSEventMask.leftMouseUp, NSEventMask.rightMouseDown, NSEventMask.rightMouseUp, NSEventMask.mouseMoved, NSEventMask.leftMouseDragged, NSEventMask.rightMouseDragged, NSEventMask.mouseEntered, NSEventMask.mouseExited, NSEventMask.keyDown, NSEventMask.keyUp, NSEventMask.flagsChanged, NSEventMask.appKitDefined, NSEventMask.systemDefined, NSEventMask.applicationDefined, NSEventMask.periodic, NSEventMask.cursorUpdate, NSEventMask.scrollWheel, NSEventMask.tabletPoint, NSEventMask.tabletProximity, NSEventMask.otherMouseDown, NSEventMask.otherMouseUp, NSEventMask.otherMouseDragged, NSEventMask.gesture, NSEventMask.magnify, NSEventMask.swipe, NSEventMask.rotate, NSEventMask.beginGesture, NSEventMask.endGesture, NSEventMask.smartMagnify, NSEventMask.pressure]

init() {
    self.eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: TrackingService.inactivityEvents) {event in
        print("event detected: \(event)")
        if self.isTracking() {
            self.idleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2 * 60, target: self, selector: #selector(TimeTrackingService.inactivityDetected(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            self.unpauseTracking()
        }
    }
}

func startService() {
    //start service will be called from a background queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.eventMonitor?.start()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What's wrong with `NSEventMask.any`? any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 'NSEventMask' has been renamed to 'NSEvent.EventTypeMask'

Answer (score 1):

I think that gestures can't be tracked globally by design.
Apple's documentation for [`addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforevents) lists `NSEvent.EventTypeMask` that should work, swipes are not among them.